# Oracle Create TABLE

Tags: oracle, ddl

I am trying to create a table with foreign key using oracle. My syntax is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE product (
   product_id       INT(7) NOT NULL,
   supplier_id      INT(7) NOT NULL,
   product_name     VARCHAR2(30),
   product_price    DOUBLE(4),
   product_category VARCHAR2(30),
   product_brand    VARCHAR2(20),
   product_expire   DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY (product_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id)
)
```

I got a error, saying

> Error at Command Line:2 Column:14 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00907:
>   missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Please help!

Comment: Your foreign key seems quite lacking.

Answer (score 3):

Your foreign key should refference another column on another table.

1. [Here is the documentation you need to fix your issue](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php) (how to write the query with the correct syntax for foreign key)
2. Also, change your data type for column product_price from `DOULBE(4)` to `NUMBER(12,4)`.

Comment: He's using the Oracle Database and not Oracle MySQL.

Comment: have tried and still got error!

Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE TABLE supplier
( supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
  supplier_name varchar2(30) not null,
  supplier_price double(5),
  supplier_address varchar2(50),
  supplier_phone varchar(15),
  CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id)
)
Error at Command Line:4 Column:23
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @user2714726 Change your data type for column `product_price` from `DOUBLE(4)` to `NUMBER(12,4)`.

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it all sort out finally

Comment: @user2714726 If this has worked for you, don't forget to mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 2):

You should not use limit for int type...oracle will take default length for int type .
Instead of int you can use Number type to make it run. And DOUBLE PRECISION is a data type in oracle but Double is not there. Also , syntax for foreign key is wrong.
so this query will work for sure :

```
CREATE TABLE product(
   product_id       number(7) NOT NULL,
   supplier_id      number(7) NOT NULL,
   product_name     VARCHAR2(30),
   product_price    DOUBLE PRECISION,
   product_category VARCHAR2(30),
   product_brand    VARCHAR2(20),
   product_expire   DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY (product_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id)
    REFERENCES parent_table (supplier_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You create like foreign key references parent table that is the proper syntax for creating the foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE product(
   product_id       number(7) NOT NULL,
   supplier_id      number(7) NOT NULL,
   product_name     VARCHAR(30),
   product_price    DOUBLE PRECISION,
   product_category VARCHAR(30),
   product_brand    VARCHAR(20),
   product_expire   DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY (product_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id)
    REFERENCES parent_table (supplier_id)
);
```